# Angular 6 + Firebase email-password authorisation. Email Verification

Tags: firebase, angular

Есть некоторое приложение с необходимостью регистрации/авторизации (Firebase -email/password).
При нажатии на условную кнопку "вход" выскакивает модальное окно с формой регистрации/авторизации. По нажатию на условную кнопку "зарегистрировать-нового-пользователя" данной формы в Firebase создается новый пользователь, и на почту, указанную при регистрации отправляется письмо со ссылкой-подтверждением.

#### Задача:

После подтверждения пользователем своего email необходимо закрыть модальное окно и перенаправить пользователя на страницу его аккаунта.

#### Мысли:

При подтверждении пользователем адреса почты значение свойства **firebase.User.emailVerified** меняется на **true**, соответственно необходимо отследить изменение значения этого свойства (это сделать не получается).

#### Вопросы:

1) Как отследить изменение значения свойства **firebase.User.emailVerified** для последующего выполнения необходимых действий? Или есть лучший способ отследить подтверждение email?
2) Как удалить созданный аккаунт Firebase, если адрес почты не подтвержден?

Фрагмент кода сервиса, используемого для регистрации/авторизации :

```
    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private modalService: ModalService, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {

  }

  // Регистрация email/password
  emailSignUp(email: string, password: string, userName: string) {

    return this.afAuth.auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(
        (currentUser) => {
          // Отправляем сообщение пользователю
          currentUser.user.sendEmailVerification();
        }
      )
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
  }
```

Comment: вот такой флоу пишет лид файрбейз https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902082/10123947

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вопрос решен.